# Kryonet: Do classes being registered have to be identical?

Tags: java, networking, serialization, packet, kryonet

I am sending some packets through kryonet that simply hold an "Entity" variable. I created the entity class myself. The thing is that when registering the entity class, the class file on the server and the client are not exactly the same.

On the client side, I did not include some methods because they rely on accessing variable that are only server side and I completely removed all constructors because the client will not be the one creating entities, the server will. On the server wide I left out the render method since the server will not be rendering.

Does it really matter what methods and constructors are there? Does kryonet only look to see if the variables are the same (cause they are)? Thanks!

By the way, if you were wondering, Entity is an abstract method and therefore when I create new types of entities like "Player" for example, they extend it and add even more methods and variable. I hope that is alright for sending those in a packet too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking but as far as I understand I will try my best to answer your question.

So I think what you are trying to do is you have a base class called Entity and you extend it to different classes. You implement some methods in class which will be sent to client and some which will be sent to server.

So as you asked does it matter what methods and constructor are there, the answer is NO. Till the time you have an empty Constructor (required by Kryo serializer) kryonet is fine with whatever constructor you have. Just you need to make sure you have an empty constructor. I have many classes in kryonet with more than 2 constructors and they work perfectly fine.

A tip, since you are sending data on network, if I was you I would have removed all the data variables which will not be used in client and abstracted out the classes even more.

Also why are you sending methods in classes? Just curious. I think you should have methods in server and client and you should take the data out of the packet (classes) and then send it to the method in your server or client.

If anything is not clear let me know.

Comment: I found the answer already by performing some tests. The only thing that needs to be identical are the variables, methods, packages or anything else simply don't matter.